# Taking only the year from material ui date picker-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
const printDate = (date) => {
  console.log(date);
};

return (
  <div style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DemoContainer components={["DatePicker"]}>
        <DatePicker label={label} views={["year"]} onChange={printDate} />
      </DemoContainer>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  </div>
);
```

In the above code I can only get console log like below picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKVRz.png)
I need to print only the year. How can I do that?

I am expecting get the year as printed output in the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `dayjs` as an adapter, your `printDate` function should look like this:

```
let printDate = (date)=>{
  console.log(date.format("YYYY"))
}
```

Comment: **This code is working** for me. I get the year from the year picker in material ui.